# How to set values for Maven's pom properties in dependencies?

Tags: sbt

What are the options to set a value for a Maven POM property for a dependency in a sbt build?

My project has a dependency to another project that's under Maven. I think I need to somehow provide a value for `my.classifier`. This is the part of the dependency's pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.mycoolproject.something</groupId>
  <artifactId>core</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <classifier>${my.classifier}</classifier>
</dependency>
```

Currently I am getting:

```
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/mycoolproject/something/core/0.4.0/core-1.0-${my.classifier}.jar
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a workaround for now with [classifiers of SBT](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.3/docs/Detailed-Topics/Library-Management.html#classifiers):

```
"the.other.dependency.that.needs.the.lib" % "x" % "1.0" exclude("com.mycoolproject.something", "core")
"com.mycoolproject.something" % "core" % "1.0" classifier "myvalue"
```